# Angular: Use same angular application in different contexts

Tags: angular, typescript, version-control, angular-ui-router, angular-library

We plan to extend two existing related websites (a customer website and a partner website) by additional functionalities.

Both platforms are developped on old technology, which we can only marginally adapt for our purposes. Thus our plan would be, to embed modern angular based-features on both websites in the existing HTML-Code.

Something like

```html
...
<jhi-input-main>
...
</jhi-input-main>
<script src="runtime.js" type="module"></script><script src="polyfills.js" type="module"></script><script src="main.js" type="module"></script>
...
```

on the partner website and

```html
...
<jhi-output-main>
  ...
</jhi-output-main>
<script src="runtime.js" type="module"></script><script src="polyfills.js" type="module"></script><script src="main.js" type="module"></script>
...
```

on the customer website.

Both applications have much Angular source code in common.
We have managed to set up either the input side, or the output side. However we were not able to manage this in a common code base.

I know, that angular is mainly focussed on single-page applications. But what is the best way to manage our code base? Are there concepts to share a common code base by different angular projects? Or is there an project internal option to expose/bootstrap different main-components?

Best regards

Michael

Comment: Are you perhaps looking to build a [library](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries)? Libraries are the perfect place for common code that's used in multiple applications.

Comment: What you want should work fine, just bootstrap the correct component? Or you can opt to use Angular Elements and create webcomponents to embed.

Comment: @MikeOne: Thank you for your feed back. We will give Angular Elements a try.